# Heterogeneous Value Difference Metric (HVDM)

Tags: machine-learning, distance

I would like to ask if someone know some examples of the Heterogeneous Value Difference Metric (HVDM) distance ? also, i would like to ask if there is an implementation of such metric in R?

I will be grateful if someone can give some useful ressource in such way i could compute this distance manually

Comment: Implementation of a HVDM is use case specific.

Comment: i would to compute the distance between two dataset that contain both numerical and nominal value. if there is an implementation or some examples of this metricsm i will be thankful.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very involved subject, which is no doubt why you can't find examples. What worries me about your question is that it is very general, and often a given implementation or use case of this sort of machine learning / data mining may need considerable algorithm tuning to make it effective, because the nature of the data will to some extent dictate how your HVDM is best calculated.

Single dimensional euclidean distance can obviously be calculated by D = a - b. 2D distance is Pythagoras, so D = SQRT((a1-b1)^2+(a2-b2)^2), and when you have N dimensional data D = SQRT((a1-b1)^2+(a2-b2)^2+....+(aN-bN)^2).

So, if you are comparing 2 data sets, a and b, with N numerical values, you can now calculate a distance between them...

Note that the square root is probably usually optional for practical purposes since it affects magnitude, but this is a tuning/performance/optimisation issue... and I'm not sure, but maybe some use cases might be better with it and some without.

Since you say your dataset has nominal values in, this makes it more interesting, as euclidean distance is meaningless for nominal values... How you reconcile that depends on the data, if you can assign numerical data to the nominals, that's good, because you can then calculate a euclidean distance again (e.g. banana = {2,4,6}, apple={4,2,2}, pear={3,3,5}, these numbers being characteristics such as shape, colour, squishiness, for example).

Next problem is that because you have nominal and numerical data which is fundamentally different, you almost certainly need to normalise the nominal and numerical so that one doesn't have an unreasonable weight because of the nature of that data. Also it's possible you might split each numerical data set and calculate 2 distances for each data set comparison... again it's a data dependant decision, or a decision you will make when tuning to get good or even sane performance. Sum the normalised results, or calculate a euclidean distance of them.

Normalising, at its simplest, means dividing by the over all range of the data, so 2 bits of data, both normalised will both be reduced to a value between 0 and 1, thus eliminating irrelevant facts like the magnitude of one bit of data is 10,000 times that of the other. Alternative normalising techniques might be appropriate for your data if it can or does have outliers.

Comment: If this does help you to write your HVDM (or if it doesn't), please come back and post your own answer for everyone’s benefit, even if you have to tweak it a bit to make if simpler or more generic.

Answer (score 1):

In R, You can find UBL Package that use HVDM as option of Distance, at ENNClassif function.

```
library(datasets)
data(iris)
summary(iris)

#install.packages("UBL")
library(UBL)

# generate an small imbalanced data set
ir<- iris[-c(95:130), ]
# use HDVM as Distance for numeric and nominal features.
irHVDM <- ENNClassif(Species~., ir, k = 3, dist = "HVDM")
```